# How do I copy a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this is a simple question, ***but***, what I mean is how do you copy a cell, but when that cell changes, it doesn't affect the copy.

To make it a bit easier to understand, If I had `A1` that said "Hi", and I wanted `A2`to say "Hi" also, I would put `=A1`. However, if I changed `A1`, it would change `A2` along with it, and that is what I don't want.

I am asking this as I have a formula that says that something is so and so weeks overdue, but when a checkbox is ticked, the weeks counter stops and doesn't add any more.

[Here is what I mean and the paragraph underneath states what it means and what I need from it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg1hz.png)

The cell that says "13/02/2019" is `=TODAY()` and the cell that says "06/02/2019" is a date I manually entered. The problem I have is that if I came back in 1 week, it would say "Handed in late by 2 weeks." and that is what I want to prevent. However, I only want this `=TODAY()` to freeze when that check box is ticked.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the formula you have that is not working as desired in the question.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to write some VBA that takes the current value of `A1` and pastes it as a value into the destination cell. Then you can change `A1` and it won't make any difference

Comment: I'm not very good with Excell and am unsure what VBA is and unsure how to write code for it.

Comment: A copy/paste operation from `A1` to `A2` should work.

Comment: I know this will work, however, I need this to translate into a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Today() reports today's date and it will always update to the current date. Today() is a volatile function that will recalculate on every worksheet change, even cells entirely unrelated to the function. Formulas referencing a cell containing Today() will also update to reflect the current date like you are experiencing now.

You appear to be looking for a process that will snapshot the date at the time of an action (checking a box). If you want it to be a formula, you will need to input the date of return as well and create a formula comparing the difference between to two inputs. There is already a shortcut to insert today's date in a non-formula method: Select the cell and press Control + ; (semi-colon). A simple formula that references the difference between the check-out and check-in dates on a per line basis with rounding and concatenate functions, should accomplish the described purpose.

A1 = (Checkout date)

B1 = (Return Date)

C1 `=IF(ROUNDUP((B1-A1)/7,0)=1,CONCATENATE(ROUNDUP((B1-A1)/7,0)," Week"),CONCATENATE(ROUNDUP((B1-A1)/7,0)," Weeks"))`

This function checks the difference between A and B, divides by 7 to get number of weeks, rounds it up to a whole number, and checks if the number of weeks is 1 or not. If it is one the text will say " week" otherwise it will say " weeks". This also avoids using a volatile function which in larger projects would cause incessant and potentially resource demanding calculating.

Comment: Doesn't really help much but I'll have to use the Ctrl+; instead of a formula. Thank you.